# How to snap an image/element to the bottom of the screen in kivy?

Tags: user-interface, kivy, kivymd

im very new to kivy and ive been trying to snap an element to the bottom of the screen, but its not working as intended

```
BoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        size : self.size
        pos : self.pos
        texture : Gradient.vertical(get_color_from_hex("141414"),get_color_from_hex("070606"))

Image:
    source: 'Icons/bg_grid.png'
    Image:
        source : 'Icons/tech.png'
        center_x: self.parent.center_x
        center_y: self.parent.top - 100
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 400,400
    Image:
        source : 'Icons/disconnected.png'
        center_x:self.parent.center_x
        center_y:self.parent.top - 200
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 125,125
    Image:
        source: 'Icons/ins2.png'
        center_x:self.parent.center_x
        center_y:self.parent.center_y
        size_hint: None, None
        size : 450,450
    Image:
        source : 'Icons/bottom.png'
        center_x:self.parent.center_x
        size_hint: None, None
        size:root.size
        pos:root.pos
    Image:
        source : 'Icons/bottom.png'
        center_x:self.parent.center_x
        size_hint: None, None
        size:root.size
        
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'top': 1} ######################## Not working
```

[image]

How do i get the floating image to snap to the bottom of the screen without using absolute units?
any help?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].